# Java array never recognizes entry

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote some java code that takes imput from the user for  the temps on any day of the week, the problem is when I enter a valid day of the week for some reason my code does not recoginize it and skips to the block that prints unknown day entered. I cannot figure out why, below is my code, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 package program7_johnhuber;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 //import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Program7_JohnHuber {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> temps = new ArrayList<>();

days.add("Monday");
days.add("Tuesday");
days.add("Wednesday");
days.add("Thursday");
days.add("Friday");
days.add("Saturday");
days.add("Sunday");


  //Set temps to 0
  for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++){
 temps.add(0.0);
}
while (true){
 System.out.print("Enter a day (Monday-Sunday): ");
 String day = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

 int index = days.indexOf(day);

 if (index == -1){
     System.out.println("You entered a unknown day.");
 }
 else{
     System.out.print("Enter the temperature for this day: ");
     double temp = input.nextDouble();
     input.nextLine();

     temps.set(index, temp);
     System.out.println("Temperature for the day recorded");
 }
 System.out.print("Do you want to enter another entry? (yes/no)");
 String choice = input.nextLine();

 if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
     break;
 }
  }
  double totalTemp = 0;
    //int i;

for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); i++){
    totalTemp += temps.get(i);
}
double averageTemp = totalTemp / temps.size();
System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s\n", "Day", "Temperature");

for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); i++){
System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s\n", days.get(i), String.format("%.2f", temps.get(i)));
} 
System.out.println("The weekly average temperature is: " + String.format("%.2f", averageTemp));
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added the days of the week yourself, you capitalized the Day. When taking input, you lowercased it all. It will never match.

Comment: so change `String day = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();` to `String day = input.nextLine();`

Answer (score -1):

You added the days with first letter in upper case and the input data is preprocessed with toLowerCase... sooo. Why do you think that indexOf should return something?

The bad news: there is no indexOf function in `ArrayList` that is case insensitive.

The good news: You can implement it by yourself very easily:

```
public class ArrayListEx<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        T param = (T)o;
        for (T s : this) {
            if (param.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

or you can use the Java8 streams:

```
days.stream().filter(dayFromDays->dayFromDays.equalsIgnoreCase(day)).collect(Collectors.toList()).size()>0
```